# How long does it take for wheat crops to grow in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been trying to grow [wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat) in [Minecraft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Wiki) but it hasn't been growing. It is in the sunlight and there is [water](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water) but it's just not growing. This is my first time growing [crops](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Crops) and I thought it was just because it takes long to grow them so I want to know how long it takes to grow them (specifically wheat).

Comment: Do we really need that many wiki links?

Comment: @frank no but i like linking stuff

Comment: If you like linking stuff, finding the article that details this should pose no difficulties.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: why did you vote it down

Comment: he means that if you found the wheat page, you can easily access [this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Crop_farming#Growth_rate)

Comment: ok but i just went there to copy the page i didn't look at anything

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from experience it has taken **1 day cycle to 6 day cycles to grow depending on if they are hydrated or not**.

The wheat crop has a total of eight stages from the time it is planted until it can be harvested.  Planted seeds need at least a light level of 9 in the block above them to grow or be exposed to the sky.

Crops will grow faster if the farmland they are planted in is hydrated. Bone meal can also be used to increase the speed of growth by causing the seeds to randomly increase their stage by 1 to 7.

If your seeds just wont grow make sure they're exposed to the sky and make sure they have direct access to water.

Reference: [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seeds)

Comment: Seeds does not need direct access to water. It needs water only in 1-4 blocks away.

Comment: Also, wheat crops will grow faster if they are planted in "rows," as in if they have an empty farmland block next to them